# It's easy to set a breakpoint when debugging VBA, but how about a "startpoint" or a "skippoint"?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm debugging a subroutine in my VBA code.  I want to ignore the first half and just run the second half.  So, is there a way to set a 'startpoint'?

Also, is there an easy way to ignore a specific line of code other than commenting?

If not, I'll just continue commenting out all the code I don't want run.  The problem with this, of course, is that I have to remember to uncomment the critical code before I send it on to Production.

Comment: Why not just put the breakpoint at the begining of the the second half of the subroutine? Also, I believe clicking the "run" button (green right-pointing arrow) should run and then stop the app at the next breakpoint, thus saving you from stepping through the code between breakpoints. There's also a "Run-to-cursor" feature (Ctrl-F8) which I've never used, but it's worth a try (I suspect it executes up to wherever you place the cursor). ;)

Comment: If I set the breakpoint at the beginning of the 2nd half, that would just run the 1st half, not the 2nd half. right?

Comment: yes, whenever you are at a breakpoint, you can hit the run button and it continues the program, but will stop at another (or same) breakpoint if it happens to catch again.

Comment: Ah, nevermind.  Placing the cursor in the 2nd half would run it from that breakpoint forward. Thanks.

Comment: @ FrustratedWithFormsDesigner, if you put your comment in an answer, I can green check it for you.

Comment: @PowerUser: yes, the breakpoint at the start of the second half means the first half would execute *without* interruption (which I assume is what you want) and then *stop* for you to debug one line at a time at the begining of the second half.

Comment: If you can run a subroutine from half way through, then it should be two subroutines at least!!

Comment: I never use it, but there is a menu option for "Debug...Set Next Statement". So you can put a breakpoint right at the start of your code, let the debugger stop you there, and then set the next statement to whatever you want and continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just put the breakpoint at the begining of the the second half of the subroutine? Also, I believe clicking the "run" button (green right-pointing arrow) should run and then stop the app at the next breakpoint, thus saving you from stepping through the code between breakpoints. There's also a "Run-to-cursor" feature (Ctrl-F8) which I've never used, but it's worth a try (I suspect it executes up to wherever you place the cursor). ;)

Comment: `Stop` can also be useful. If this='that' Then Stop

Comment: also Debug.Assert (this <> "that")

Answer (score 0):

Is it just one routine?

Would a GoTo Statement work for you in this case:

```
Sub DoTheMagic()
   Dim vars as whatever

   GoTo TheFunStuff
   'The impertinent code here
TheFunSuff:
    'The code to debug here
End Sub
```

You'd have to remember to take that goto statement out before you went to production.  A annoying messagebox would remind you do that.